# how to assign a missing value in dataframe by another value of dataframe?

Tags: r

My dataframe is like this

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
abc        25    35
cde  asd   25    45
def        15    36
erf        23    69
erf  asd   25    36
erf  dfg   85    78
```

convert to like this

```
col1 col2 col3 col4  col5
abc        25    35    abc
abc  asd   25    45    asd
def        15    36    def
erf        23    69    erf
erf  asd   25    36    asd
erf  dfg   85    78    dfg
```

i need the col5 value but i amnot getting it.
i Have tried using ifelse
My code is

```
data$col5 <- ifelse(data$col2 =="",levels(data$col1),levels(data$col2))
```

But I am getting the wrong value.

Comment: why are you using `levels(data$col1)` inside ifelse?

Comment: else the value are coming as numeric in the col5

Comment: @JaikumarS Use `as.character` instead of `levels`.

Comment: If we have a huge data for about 100 observation it coming in sorting order so it getting a wrong value..

Comment: Try Roland suggestion, though I would do the following `indx <- max.col(data[1:2] != "", ties.method = "last") ; data$col5 <- data[cbind(seq_len(nrow(data)), indx)]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per @Rolands comment

```
data$col5 <- ifelse(data$col2 =="",as.character(data$col1),,as.character(data$col2))
```